# R code review the z-score for the maximum value

Tags: r

I need to calculate the z-scores for the maximum values. My code keeps on erroring out. Could I have some assistance?

Sample code:

```
z_scores <- scores(mtcars$mpg, type = "z")
which(abs(z_scores) > 2)
```

Comment: Where does the `scores` function come from?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `scores()` function - is it from a package? What error are you getting?

Comment: I get this error message: Error in which(abs(z_scores) > 2) : object 'z_scores' not found

Comment: That might be because you did not read the previous error message when you ran `z_scores <- scores(mtcars$mpg, type = "z")`

Comment: Sportsguy3090, read the comments: *where is `scores` defined*? Type in `scores` on the console (no parens, nothing else) and then hit enter, then tell us the `namespace:` it returns.

Comment: When I do that I get: Error: object 'scores' not found

Comment: Imagine my surprise. What tutorial, howto, or class-notes are you following that suggested to use a pre-existing function named `scores`? If you look further back in that document, is there a call to `library(.)` or `require(.)` that you forgot to execute? Even if you ran all such calls, did any of them say *"there is no package called '...'"*? There might be some useful candidates to jog your memory here: [`cran "scores"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+"scores"). Hope this helps you find the library you need!

Comment: Perhaps `scores` is from [the outliers package](https://rdrr.io/cran/outliers/man/scores.html). In which case you need to install it and then use `library(outliers)`.

Comment: Honestly this is my first time programing in R. I do apologize this is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the arguments to `scores`, I think it comes from the [outliers package](https://rdrr.io/cran/outliers/man/scores.html).

So install if you don't have it:

```
install.packages("outliers")
```

and then:

```
library(outliers)

z_scores <- scores(mtcars$mpg, type = "z")
which(abs(z_scores) > 2)
```

Result:

```
[1] 18 20
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: (This package is oddly *not* at the top of the list of googled CRAN packages with `scores` in it. Nice find, neilfws.)

Comment: Yes, quite difficult to discover. I used the argument in the Google search.